# Using JavaScript to modify the content of html

Tags: javascript, php, html, database

Now I am doing a shopping cart in my project, when i click the add to cart button, then it will upload the data in localstorage, then i will create an element (product name, price, quantity and two increment and decrement button in the list) and this create process will be looped by the length of localstorage.

When I want to make click event on increment and decrement button, only the last row of increment and decrement button respond. For example, I have 3 rows in shopping cart, only the third row will show the proper result, the first two row have no response.

I would like to ask can you give me some suggestion, how to achieve my goal? Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

```
var ul = document.getElementById("cart")
    for(var i=0;i<localStorage.length;i++){
    var li = document.createElement("li");
    
    var addBtn =document.createElement("BUTTON");   
    var dropBtn document.createElement("BUTTON");
    addBtn.innerHTML = '+';
    dropBtn.innerHTML = '-';
    addBtn.id='addBtn'
    var a = document.getElementById("addBtn")
    addBtn.onclick = function(){
        alert('here be addBtn');return false;
    };
    dropBtn.onclick = function(){
        alert('here be dropBtn');return false;
    };
    ul.appendChild(addBtn);
    ul.appendChild(dropBtn);
    ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

Comment: Why to search for `addBtn` when you have already created and has reference to button. Use that reference to add event listener. Similarly with the `dropBtn`

Comment: but you need to change the id of the button as ID should be unique

Comment: Also, why are you appending those buttons to the _list_, should they not be appended to the current _list item_?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some changes to work as expected:

- Not to search/find button when you have its reference.
- append a button to list i.e. `li` not to `ul` (Thanks CBroe).

I've taken some assumption like the `localStorage` length as `3` and added the text of the cart button.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector("ul#cart");
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var li = document.createElement("li");

  var addBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var dropBtn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
  var text = document.createElement("span");
  text.textContent = ` item${i+1} `
  addBtn.innerHTML = '+';
  dropBtn.innerHTML = '-';
  addBtn.id = `addBtn${i+1}`;
  dropBtn.id = `dropBtn${i+1}`;

  addBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    alert(`here be addBtn with id ${e.target.id}`);
  })
  dropBtn.addEventListener('click', e => {
    alert(`here be dropBtn with id ${e.target.id}`);
  })

  li.appendChild(addBtn);
  li.appendChild(text);
  li.appendChild(dropBtn);
  ul.appendChild(li);
}
```

```html
<ul id="cart"></ul>
```